# How to start video recording with same time interval when click on start recording?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, video, avcapturesession

I have implemented the video and audio recording with avcapturesession. It is taking some to start recording that usually ~1 or 2 seconds.

If require more information feel free comments. 
Setup capture session doing below steps:

- add capture session
- add video input
- add audio input
- add video preview layer
- add movie output
- set up camera configuration for output connection
- start capture session

  -(void)setupCaptureSession {

  ```
   // Set up capture session
       captureSession = [AVCaptureSession new];

  //add video intput
  AVCaptureDevice *videoCaptureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

     if (videoCaptureDevice) {
      NSError *error;

      videoInputDevice =  [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:videoCaptureDevice error:&error];
      if(!error){
          if ([captureSession canAddInput:videoInputDevice]) {
              [captureSession addInput:videoInputDevice];
          }else{
              NSLog(@"Failed to add video input");
          }
      }else{
          NSLog(@"Failed to create video device");
      }
  }else{
      NSLog(@"Failed to create video capture device");
  }

  // add audio input
  AVCaptureDevice *audioCaptureDevie = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];

  NSError *error = nil;

  AVCaptureDeviceInput *audioInputDevice = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:audioCaptureDevie error:&error];
  if (audioInputDevice) {
      [captureSession addInput:audioInputDevice];
  }

  // add outputs

  // add video preview layer
  NSLog(@"Adding video preview layer");

  [self setPreviewLayer:[[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:captureSession]];

  [[self previewLayer] setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];

  //add movie ouput
  movieFileOutput = [[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc] init];
  movieFileOutput.minFreeDiskSpaceLimit = 1024 * 1024;

  if ([captureSession canAddOutput:movieFileOutput])
      [captureSession addOutput:movieFileOutput];

  // set up camera configuration for output connection
  [self setUpCameraConfiguration];

  [captureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium];
  if ([captureSession canSetSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480])
      [captureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480];



  //----- DISPLAY THE PREVIEW LAYER -----
  //Display it full screen under out view controller existing controls
  NSLog(@"Display the preview layer");
  CGRect layerRect = [[[self view] layer] bounds];
  [_previewLayer setBounds:layerRect];
  [_previewLayer setPosition:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(layerRect),
                                         CGRectGetMidY(layerRect))];
  //[[[self view] layer] addSublayer:[[self CaptureManager] previewLayer]];
  //We use this instead so it goes on a layer behind our UI controls (avoids us having to manually bring each control to the front):
  UIView *cameraView = [[UIView alloc] init];
  [[self view] addSubview:cameraView];
  [self.view sendSubviewToBack:cameraView];

  [[cameraView layer] addSublayer:_previewLayer];


  //----- START THE CAPTURE SESSION RUNNING -----
  [captureSession startRunning];
  ```

  }

Comment: 1. Add your session configuration code.
2. Add the code of starting recording. 
3. Did you create a separate DispatchGroup to work with AVCaptureSession?

Comment: I would say that might be related to not doing things in the background but we need more info first. Can you share the code?

Comment: Please refer this link it may help you. https://github.com/changsanjiang/SJRecordVideo